# CKAN getting INFO about SmartCities

Tags: ckan, fiware, cosmos, filab

I'm trying to get access to CKAN in order to work the same way as with Cosmos.
In this case I'll prefer to use HTTP commands (I've heard it's possible) to use it in any app.
Where may I get some information?

Answer (score 1):

See the [API Guide](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/index.html), that should help.